# Is there a full list of Java non-terminals?

Tags: java, computer-science

I already found the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) but I'm not sure if the non-terminals listed on [point 2.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.4) are a complete list of all non-terminals. How many non-terminals does Java have?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html), look for anything in an italic font, as described in Sec 2.4.

Comment: @JacobKrall done.

Comment: I point out that which constitutes a terminal depends upon your grammar.

Answer (score 3):

Point 2.4 is merely explaining how the grammar notation works. The complete list is contained in following chapters.

> The syntactic grammar for the Java programming language is given in
>   Chapters 4, 6-10, 14, and 15. This grammar has tokens defined by the
>   lexical grammar as its terminal symbols. It defines a set of
>   productions, starting from the goal symbol CompilationUnit (§7.3),
>   that describe how sequences of tokens can form syntactically correct
>   programs.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for specific parts of the language is scattered throughout the language spec; but it is all gathered together in [Chapter 19. syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-19.html).

You can look for the non-terminals in there, noting from Sec 2.4 that they are written in italic font.